# How avoid extra space between paragraphs in Outlook 2013 when displaying plain text messages?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, text-formatting

Outlook 2013 has suddenly started putting extra space between paragraphs when displaying messages formatted as *plain text*. This applies to both outgoing and incoming messages. But if I view plain text messages using my ISP's webmail facility, they look the way they should. I therefore believe this is an Outlook display issue.

As an example, the following picture shows a message on my screen just before I send it (left), when I receive it (middle), and in my ISP's webmail client:
[image]
This is new behavior. Outlook didn't do this a few days ago. How can I get it to not do it again?

Comment: Have you install any updates before the issue occurred? Does this problem affect all users in your environment? Try checking if the checkbox of "Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages" is selected via File > Options > Mail > Mail Format.

Comment: I may have installed some Windows updates recently. I'm not sure of the exact date when the problem began. (I was busy with work and didn't have time to try to track down the Outlook problem.) I'm the only user. The status of the "Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages" checkbox makes no difference.